# Google chart from SQL Server database using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, google-visualization

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong here?

connecting to database

```
$sql = "SELECT name , pname FROM [org]";    

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn , $sql  );    

if ( $stmt )    
{    

}     
else     
{    
 echo "Error in statement execution.\n";    
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));    
 }       
?>
```

Trying the sample code from google charts

```
<html>
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {packages:["orgchart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

   function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
    data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

    data.addRows([

         <?php
               while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt))    
     {  
                         echo "['".$row[0]."', '".$row[1]."' ,''],";
                     }

             ?>
            ]);
```

Nothing appears on the page when I run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make your code like this.

```
<?php
$array = array();
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt))    
{  
    $array[] = array($row[0],$row[1]);
}
$addrows = json_encode($array);

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {packages:["orgchart"]});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
    data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

    data.addRows(<?php echo $addrows; ?>);
```

Comment: @AhmedOmer select the answer if helped.